# Delete part of string by indicator in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to delete the ending part of a string where the beginning and end are variable but have several indicators. The string I'm working with is "Num1_xc_min_20201229_112401.rdf".

The Num1 is variable and the 20201229_112401 is variable (since it's a date). Num1 will not always have four characters. The end result I want is "Num1". *xc* is always constant.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
Sub Macro1()

        Dim input1 As String
        Dim remove1 As String
        Dim result1 As String
        input1 = Range("C2").Value
        remove1 = "_xc_*"    'this is the char to be removed
        result1 = Replace(input1, LCase(remove1), "")
        Range("C2").Value = result1
End Sub
```

This hasn't worked because you can't set a variable equal to a like statement.

Comment: ```split(input1, "_")(0)```

Comment: I haven't used the split function yet! I feel like an idiot. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Split by the `remove1` value and return the first (0-th) element:

```
Sub Macro1()
    
    Dim input1 As String
    Dim remove1 As String
    
    input1 = "Num1_xc_min_20201229_112401.rdf"
    remove1 = "_xc_"
    Debug.Print Split(input1, remove1)(0)
    
End Sub
```

Returns `Num1`.